# VBA to find maximum value in a chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data columns A, B, and C. I have displayed as a line graph with B as the primary axis and C as the secondary axis. Column A is the category axis. I want to find the maximum value of column C and put a data callout on the point that is the maximum of column C and where column B occurs.

I know this sounds confusing. In this example, the maximum of Column C occurs at Point 27 (or 1.50% on the category axis). I would like a dot at point 27 for both Column B and C.

Column A is percentage from -5.00 to 10.00 incremented at .25%. Columns B and C are plotted against the change.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have done something similar, use a formula in column D to identify the largest number in Column C and B and make it a value high on your chart if the result is true.

Add Column D as a series to the chart.

Change the chart type on that series only to a scatter chart or something that puts points up there.

You can put a label on or simply put the amount showing above the plotted point.

You don't need VBA for this.

Comment: Thanks Dan;I have seen that solution, and I think it may be what I will do. I was hoping for something in VBA, but I know the Max formula will do the trick. My issue was this chart is part of a dashboard and I want it to look as clean as possible. There are of course ways to hide anything extraneous though.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested to know I found a solution that works for me. First, I added columns D and E using the formula =IF(C2=MAX(C$2:C$62),C2,NA()) and =IF(C2=MAX(C$2:C$62),B2,NA()), this gave me the point on the graph for both lines B and C where B was maximum. I then formatted the graph so that these points had data callouts (a request from the client). Finally, I set columns D and E to have white font, to match the background so the appear invisible. I don't love this step, but I don't want the client to see the extra rows of #NA, etc.

The basic VBA for data callout is     ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCallout)

Where the series is 5 (column E) and I'm putting a data callout on the graphed point, which happens to be the maximum of column 3.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back @Matthew Ingle, it's always good to get the final solution in here for anyone who is searching for similar problems down the track. Glad you got it all worked out :).